# How can I align divs in a row without wrapping them in a container?

Tags: css

How can I align two divs, "Label 1" and "Label 2", inside of the card as shown in the image below?

[image]

```css
.card {
  position: relative;
}

.card .label1 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 16px;
}

.card .label2 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="image"><img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/140/100" /></div>
  <div class="title">Title</div>
  <div class="description">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="label1">Label 1</div>
  <div class="label2">Label 2</div>
</div>
```

I need to align "Label 1" and "Label 2", so they are located in one row and follow each other. It may also happen that one of the labels is not there, so I can not have fixed position for each of them. I can not put the labels in a container element (e.g. I can't wrap `label1` and `label2` in a `<div>`).

Comment: And tell us what you want to achieve. Align to what?

Comment: flexbox with justify-content: space-around

Comment: Is your question aligning two divs, or achieving that layout ?

Comment: The question is about aligning.

Comment: How *exactly* do you want the labels aligned? It's clear that you want them in a row, but your drawing shows them *not* proportionally aligned within that row. So, *exactly* how do you want them positioned horizontally (given that you want them vertically in-line)? What other requirements do you have? You've said you can't use a container element for the labels. Does that mean you can't change the HTML *at all*? And if so, why not?

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox can do that without additional wrappers.

The trick here is to set the containers above the labels to be 100% wide and center the contents.

```css
.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 80%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 1em auto;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 1em;
}

.image,
.title,
.description {
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.label1,
.label2 {
  background: red;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="image"><img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/140/100" /></div>
  <div class="title">Title</div>
  <div class="description">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="label1">Label 1</div>
  <div class="label2">Label 2</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope it might help you

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style>
    .card {
      width: 250px;
      height: 250px;
      border: 1px solid red;
      display: flex;
      padding: 5px;
      text-align: center;
      justify-content: space-around;
    }
    
    .label {
      padding: 10px;
      width: 80px;
      height: 20px;
      text-align: center;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="card">
      <div class="label">Label 1</div>
      <div class="label">Label 2</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not have label container

Comment: check my updated answer, hope this is what you needs

Comment: @NattamaiJawaharlalManikandan, I think your answer will break if we add one more element to the div.card. So to achieve the above structure without using any extra container you have to use "position: absolute" for labels, see my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AkshayaKT/txqLkjzf/). Please note that is not a good practice to use position because it doesn't provide any flexibility.